# Remote Server Machine 462 error when running code 2nd time

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm trying to create a macro which compares 2 documents, and leaves open the comparison document. On the first run through it works fine, but on the second, it brings up error 462 - The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable.

I've read through others posts relating to this, but none of the solutions seem to prevent the error on my macro.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks

```
Sub Compare()


        Dim wordApp As Word.Application
        Dim objMain, objComp As Word.Document

        Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
        Set wb = Workbooks("test.xlsm")

        Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
        Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

        On Error Resume Next
        Set wordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
        If wordApp Is Nothing Then
            Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        End If

        path = Excel.Application.ActiveWorkbook.path

        ''''''''''PUT FILE NAMES NEXT TO EACH OTHER GOING DOWN ON EXCEL, SO FRL on A1 and A2, STAGE 2 FRL on B1 and B2 etc

        For i = 1 To 2

            ''''THIS IS FOR THE CASE HANDLERS SAVED TEMPLATES
            On Error Resume Next
            Set objMain = wordApp.Documents.Open(path & "\..\" & ws.Range("O" & i)) '''''THIS WILL PICK THE RANGE ON EXCEL WHICH HAS THE PATH NAME FOR THE FILE

            On Error GoTo lostFile
            Select Case i
                ''''''''''''THESE WILL NEED TO BE THE ACTUAL PATHS TO THE TEMPLATES
                Case 1: Set objMain = wordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\daryl\Desktop\excelTest\test1.docx") '''''STAGE 1 FRL
                Case 2: Set objMain = wordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\daryl\Desktop\excelTest\test11.docx") '''''STAGE 2 FRL
                'etc etc
            End Select


            ''''THIS IS FOR THE TEMPLATES ON SHAREPOINT
            On Error Resume Next
            Set objComp = wordApp.Documents.Open(path & "\..\" & ws.Range("P" & i)) '''''THIS WILL PICK THE RANGE ON EXCEL WHICH HAS THE PATH NAME FOR THE FILE

            On Error GoTo lostFile2
            Select Case i
                ''''''''''''THESE WILL NEED TO BE THE ACTUAL PATHS TO THE TEMPLATES
                Case 1: Set objComp = wordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\daryl\Desktop\excelTest\test2.docx") '''''STAGE 1 FRL
                Case 2: Set objComp = wordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\daryl\Desktop\excelTest\test22.docx") '''''STAGE 2 FRL
                'etc etc
            End Select

            ''''''''''''''''IF BOTH FILES FOUND, CONTINUE ON!''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

            On Error GoTo 0
            wordApp.Visible = True
            objMain.Activate

            With wordApp
                .ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = True
                .TrackRevisions = True
                .Application.CompareDocuments OriginalDocument:=Documents(objMain), RevisedDocument:=Documents(objComp), Destination:=wdCompareDestinationNew, _
                    Granularity:=wdGranularityWordLevel, CompareFormatting:=True, _
                    CompareCaseChanges:=True, CompareWhitespace:=True, CompareTables:=True, _
                    CompareHeaders:=True, CompareFootnotes:=True, CompareTextboxes:=True, _
                    CompareFields:=True, CompareComments:=True, CompareMoves:=True, _
                    RevisedAuthor:="Daryl Boakes", IgnoreAllComparisonWarnings:=False
                .ActiveWindow.ShowSourceDocuments = wdShowSourceDocumentsBoth
                .ActiveWindow.View.SplitSpecial = wdPaneRevisions

            End With

            objMain.Close
            objComp.Close

        Next i

        wordApp.Activate

        Exit Sub

    lostFile:
        MsgBox "The first file cannot be found", vbOKOnly
        GoTo finish

    lostFile2:
        MsgBox "The second file cannot be found", vbOKOnly
        GoTo finish

    finish:


    End Sub
```

Comment: what were the solutions you tried and what happened?

Comment: Have you quit the applications as well?

Comment: Which line of your code is throwing the error?

Comment: All very good questions! I'm trying to avoid quitting the application if possble, as other people will be using it and I want it to be as user friendly as possible.

Comment: "ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = True"  is the line which is throwing the error. Interestingly, if I put "on error goto finish" just before the activedocument line, the code won't work the 2nd, 3rd, 4th time etc. Where as if that error line isn't there, the code gets the error message in the title, then runs fine

Comment: The solutions from other posts I've read were regarding ensuring VBA is aware which program each element is from, so ive declared word or excel before each dim. Ive also ensured a new instance of word is only opened if word is not already opened. Neither helped.

Comment: It might help if you correctly release the Word objects. For example: `Set wordApp = Nothing` somewhere before `End Sub`